# How to add background attr inside of PHP echo?

Tags: php

I'm trying to include a background image to `.win_box` as an attr. But because I'm using PHP to echo, the quotes are conflicting.

I don't want to use `<style>` because each `.win_box` may have a different image and I don't want to assign a separate id for each (dynamic).

```
<?php 
echo "<div class='col-xs-5 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-2' id='title'> <a href='#' class='win_link'> <div class='win_box' style='background: url("https://i.ytimg.com/vi/8sME-VxUQQA/hqdefault.jpg?custom=true&w=196&h=110&stc=true&jpg444=true&jpgq=90&sp=68&sigh=EgyGW3D0KWyu5ei-2aUz8FPI_Jc");'> <i class="fa fa-play" aria-hidden="true" id='video'></i>

   <div class='description'> Earn 5 Points </div>

   </div> </a>
  </div>";
?>
```

Comment: "because I'm using PHP to echo, the quotes are conflicting" Am I missing the reason for this? I don't see any PHP here other _than_ the `echo`…

Comment: @Chris The echo is inside a PHP while loop. I left the loop out because it's not relevant :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to either escape the quotes, or use echo with single quotes (which will let you use double quotes normally. For example:

```
<?php 
echo '
<a href="#" class="win_link"> 
  <div class="win_box" style="background: url(\'https://i.ytimg.com/vi/8sME-VxUQQA/hqdefault.jpg?custom=true&w=196&h=110&stc=true&jpg444=true&jpgq=90&sp=68&sigh=EgyGW3D0KWyu5ei-2aUz8FPI_Jc\');"> 
    <i class="fa fa-play" aria-hidden="true" id="video"></i>
    <div class="description"> Earn 5 Points </div>
  </div>
</a>';
```

Comment: Alright, it should work now. The url should have been wrapped in escaped single quotes.